# Switching on the result of a regex comparison in a case statement with Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, switch-statement

I am trying to concat a regex to a `case` statement:

I basically want to match a url that is `news/asdd-asdadas-assas.aspx`

I have other url's matched for added an active class to the navigation. The urls are made from page routes.

I have been doing this `var pathName = window.location.pathname;`

```
var re = "/[^news][\w\W]+/";
switch (pathName) {
    case "/":
        $('#home-active').addClass('active');
        break;
    case "/about-us.aspx":
        $('#about-active').addClass('active');
        break;
```

and so on ..

but i want to do this:

```
case "/news"+re:
        $('#news-active').addClass('active');
        break;
```

I have tried many different Regex, am I doing it the correct way with the `case`?

How will I match the url by concatenating the `re` variable

Comment: You can't use regex in a case clause. The *value* in a case clause has to be a possible *exact* match (===) for the expression in the switch statement. See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch

Comment: you cannot match the url by concatenating the `re` variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not the proper way to use regex in `Javascript`. Regex matching returns true/false. This means that in your case statements you would end up with something like

`pathName === pathName.match(re)`

which translates to

`pathName === true` or `pathName === false`

which *may* actually evaluate if `pathName` is not `null` or `undefined`, but almost certainly will not result in the behavior that you are expecting.

EDIT: it looks like according to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) reference provided by @JonathanM, that the case statement almost certainly will not evaluate when the parameter passed into the switch evaluates to either true or false.

Would you consider modifying your code to use the `.match()` method?

```
if(pathName.match(re)){
    $('#home-active').addClass('active');
}else if(pathName.match(re2)){
    $('#about-active').addClass('active');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use test method of regular expressions , which returns true if it matches

```
  var re = /[^news][\w\W]+/;

      case "/news".match(re)[0]:
          $('#news-active').addClass('active');
          break;
```

Comment: This won't work. The case statement doesn't execute if the value if true. It executes if the value is an exact match (===) for the value of the expression in the switch statement. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch

Answer (score 1):

Your solution does not work, because you are using a regex in your case statement. One has to match the regex and than put it in the case statement:

```
var url = "news/asdd-asdadas-assas.aspx";
var regex = new RegExp('\/.*?(.aspx)', 'g'); // from '/' to '.aspx'
var match = url.match(regex)[0]; // matches everything behind news and returns a string

case("/news" + match) ...
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/tyktxye6/)